# Can't get JSON in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I'm trying to use jQuery's ajax method to make a post request to rails.  If I send form.elements(), the content type of the request is urlencoded and rails is able to populate params with the right values, but the browser expects the response to be html so respond_to format.json throws an exception (ActionController::UnknownFormat).

```
coffeescript:
$(document).on(
    click: ->
      $.ajax
        url: "/projects.json"
        type: "POST"
        contentType: 'json'
        dataType: 'json'
        data: JSON.stringify($('form#new_project').elements())
        success: activateProgressBar
      return false
    , '#submit-button'
  )

Log:    
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Eonu3puxtkBUTtyDQNbE059Racfrwu06q/FzwKm1hWE=", "BusinessUnit"=>{"sbu"=>"2"}, "project"=>{"parent_id"=>"1", "project_num"=>"04479", "client_id"=>"101", "project_type_id"=>"1", "name"=>"ascac", "summary"=>"acacac"}, "User"=>{"approver_id"=>"115"}}
```

If I set the data using serializeArray, the request goes through as JSON, but params doesn't have the form data.

```
Coffeescript:
  $(document).on(
    click: ->
      $.ajax
        url: "/projects.json"
        type: "POST"
        contentType: 'json'
        dataType: 'json'
        data: JSON.stringify($('form#new_project').serializeArray())
        success: activateProgressBar
      return false
    , '#submit-button'
  )

Log:
Processing by ProjectsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"projects", "format"=>"json"}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the method of submitting a form with `remote: true` option?

Comment: Played with that a bit this morning.  It sends the request as Javascript, but still behaves like the urlencoded request - it gets the data in params, but doesn't respond back/call the success method.

Comment: You respond with a index.js.erb file, it's actually very handy. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the form_for in the view based on @Iceman's hint and copious googling:

```
form_for @proj, remote: true, html: {:'data-type' => 'application/json'} do |f|
```

The data comes through in the params, though not in a paramy format:

```
Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"name"=>"utf8", "value"=>"✓"}, {"name"=>"BusinessUnit[sbu]", "value"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"project[parent_id]", "value"=>"1"}, {"name"=>"project[project_num]", "value"=>"04512"}, {"name"=>"project[client_id]", "value"=>"101"}, {"name"=>"User[approver_id]", "value"=>"115"}, {"name"=>"project[project_type_id]", "value"=>"1"}, {"name"=>"project[name]", "value"=>"sxasx"}, {"name"=>"project[summary]", "value"=>"sxasx"}], "project"=>{}}
```

I turn that into a usable hash with this bit of code:

```
@form_data = Hash[ params[:_json].map(&:values) ]
```

I don't know whether this is the correct way to go about this, but it works and I need to move on to other things.

BTW, the ajax call ended up looking like this:

```
  form_data = JSON.stringify($('#new_project').serializeArray())
  $.ajax
    url: "/projects.json"
    type: "POST"
    contentType: 'application/json'
    dataType: 'json'
    data: form_data
    success: activateProgressBar
```